# Weblogic 10.3.4 throwing NullPointerException When Migrated to Jsf 2

Tags: jsf-2, deployment, weblogic11g

I am getting the below error after deploying the ear in the Weblogic and when run the application getting the error in managed server.

```
weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1428563468613>           <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@5107514[app:CustomerCentralEAR module:/CP2      path:/CP2 spec-version:2.5]] Root cause of ServletException.
    java.lang.NullPointerException  at        com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java      :228)  at      com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHand       lingStrategy.java:213)
   at com   .sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
      at   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at w        eblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
   at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
     at           weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.tms.cdqi.presentation.http.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:535)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.tms.cdqi.framework.http.filter.CDQISecurityFilter.doFilter(CDQISecurityFilter.java:96)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.tms.cdqi.framework.http.filter.CDQIXScriptingFilter.doFilter(CDQIXScriptingFilter.java:44)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.tms.cdqi.framework.http.filter.CDQIPerformanceFilter.doFilter(CDQIPerformanceFilter.java:88)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)**
```

**Below is the web.xml I'm using**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <web-app 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  id="YourWebappID" 
   version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
<param-value>.jsp</param-value>
</context-param>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>        
  </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!--    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```